# 3D extruded Bezier not filling

Tags: 3d-printing, extrude, bezier-curves

I Have an object made out of 2 merged Bezier curves (one 2D and one 3D) that I extrude in the Z-Axis and I can't manage to fill the object. I know this is a typical issue but I could not find my way around out of the help from other Q&A in the forum.

Any help / suggestion?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: 3D Bezier Curves can't be filled in Blender unfortunately, either turn it into a 2D Curve type or fill it by hand.

Comment: Thank you. I assume if I want to keep the flexibility of the bezier curves, is that I fill it by hand. Do you know how to do this? Sorry I am only using Blender for a day.

Comment: You would probably have to convert (a copy of) your curve to a mesh object and manually fill the gaps with faces. It will be a boring laborious task, especially if you want proper topology. Ideally each loop would have to have  the same number of faces.